# CSS Menu Item Styling in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I was trying to add vertical lines that appear to the very left that are animated based on hover action (this functionality already exists for the uncollapsed menu items, just as horizontal underlines that transition between scaleX(0) and scaleX(1) states). I was wanting these lines to happen on the dropdown menu items on the uncollapsed dropdown menu items and the collapsed menu items for sm and xs screens. Take a look at what I have now. I was trying to pull this effect off using a:before and background-color with scaleY but it is proving difficult. Any help greatly appreciated.

```css
 /* navbar */
 .navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
 }
 /* title */
 .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
 .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {

 }

 /* link */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #777;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:before {
  background-color: #1C86EE;
  
   content: "";
   height: 3px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
   transform: scaleX(0);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:before,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus:before {
    visibility: visible;
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
   transform: scaleX(1);
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active:before{
 background-color: #FFA500;
    visibility: visible;
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
   transform: scaleX(1);
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 /* caret */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-bottom-color: #000000;
 }

 .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
 }

 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus{
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
 }

 .dropdown-menu > li > a.active {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">Brand</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="vertical-line"></span>Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="vertical-line"/>Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="vertical-line"/>Something else here</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>          
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.nav > li > a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('ul.nav > li > a').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');                
    });    
   });
   </script>
    </html>
  </body>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('ul.nav > li > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.nav > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');                
   });    
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed the issue with the dropdown. Your `data-` attribute had a space in it, `data- toggle="collapse"`.

Comment: Thank you hungerstar. I also modified the dropdown when collapsed so everything is working to see my problem now. I would like left vertical, instead of underlines to appear in dropdown menu items when full screen and when navbar is collapsed (all menu items are dropdown) on sm and xs . Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: A great example is here. http://bootsnipp.com/ (hover over dropdown menu items in navbar); except, I want the same styling I have currently with my horizontal underline to appear vertically.

Comment: Please provide us a JsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) of your code. That makes it a lot easier for us to see what you've got already and where things are going wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jstafford75/4L114Lrd/ ; John, I am just struggling to find a way to create the left vertical lines (see bootsnip's dropdown menu items in navbar) that appear on hover for dropdown menu items. I can only seem to accomplish the horizontal underline based on an example I modified.

Comment: Are you trying to draw a vertical line up/down the drop down links or have it float in from the side like the Bootsnip menu?

Comment: Like the bootsnip menu dropdowns that have the vertical line on left.